# Cannot access shared libraries after debian linux headers installation with suid

Tags: c++, linux, debian, shared-libraries

I am working on a tool which is used boost shared objects. The tool needed to be run as a normal user. To do that I have granted suid permissions to the tool.

Everything worked well until I have installed linux-headers-4.9.0-4-amd64. After installation, the tool is not able to use shared objects. (**The tools works well with root user or sudo**)

Here is the error: `error while loading shared libraries: libboost_atomic-mt.so.1.66.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. Does anyone have any idea? (debian version: 9.3, debian repo version: 9.8)

[Permissions of shared objects:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaMOp.png)

[Permissions of tools:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71gMH.png)

[The error screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG1br.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a bug fix related to my issue. You may check if you have such kind of trouble.

Here is the bug about the SUID: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=884615

Here is the changelog: https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/g/glibc/glibc_2.24-11+deb9u4_changelog

[Related screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkn0w.png)